# No audio on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I know that specifics are what get answers, but unfortunately here's where I'm at. I don't fully understand how the linux system works and operates. I do enjoy it because I feel like there are so many options. I get a lot more control over what I do/can do vs when on a windows machine.

I can't get any audio on my distro since upgrading. Before the update, I had the option to raise and lower my volume, but now the option is gone or incomplete looking. In the gui for the audio settings, it does not list anything as an output option. My laptop's soundcard isn't listed, my earphones/headphones don't show up when I'm plugged in, and I can't plug into speakers to get any audio. Does anyone know the next step?

I've tried a few different things people have recommended online with no avail, and I don't remember the different things I tried exactly, so if you give me options, even if I've already tried it, it'll be very appreciated. When I run Kali live, it DOES have audio so I know I messed up my system somehow. I just don't know how to figure out where I went wrong exactly because there were 400 updates available.

(I've edited this to include the list of my sources that were used to update/upgrade my distro)

[image]

Comment: When you say 'updated', I take it you mean `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: That is correct. I should've at least mentioned that, sorry

Comment: Did you edit your sources.list?

Comment: Can you give me the output of ` arecord -l` and `record -L`?

Comment: Sure thing, here you go.

Comment: root@HP-PC:~# arecord -l
arecord: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
root@HP-PC:~# record -L
bash: record: command not found

Comment: It might be easier to backup everything and reinstall. (If you want a quick way to reinstall your tools, use PTF by TrustedSec)

Comment: Alright, so unfortunately I decided to go with just backing up my documents and just making a list of programs I need to reinstall, then reinstalling my system. Though it is an effective solution, I was hoping I'd be able to figure out what was wrong exactly and how to fix it. Problem is solved though, and I appreciate the help. Glad to have my audio back and have things be as they should.

Comment: Don't mess with your sources.list again :)

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say don't mess with the sources list file, more like don't add things just without fully knowing what they all are. This time I made a backup of my original

Comment: No,  for real, just don't edit it http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Comment: systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me, I had this issues in Kali 2016.2. Found it in cybrary.it

1. Open Terminal
2. Copy and Paste this command

   ```
   systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio
   ```
3. You may need to reboot

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands:

1. `lpsci` , to get the name of your audio device
2. `apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss`
3. `alsamixer`

At this stage your terminal will look like a DJ mixer.
Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to select your sound card.
If there is a column where it is marked MM (which means mute) navigate to it (directions buttons) and press <kbd>M</kbd> (to unmute).
Now if it is marked 0 so press up arrow to increase the volume.